# Code encoding from online testing site

Tags: java, encoding

I've got this code on some site for IT testing. Of course after few questions, I've thought: Why cant I copy question`s code to IDEA to check answer. But I couldnt copy it(Ctrl-C, right click, etc), and source code was with tags. So I used Ctrl-P(Chrome) to check print option and it worked, I get code. I can view this code correctly in every text editor and IDEA too, but cant compile it. Here's used some 'interesting' encoding for some symbols(maybe different for each symbol?), and after saving it for example with notepad++ with ASCII option I get the same issue. I use Windows.

For example word

> 'рublіс'

Here`s exception from compileonline.com

```
Go.java:2: error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
    ??ubl????
```

Here`s piece of the question code

```
сlаss Gо {  
      рublіс statіс vоіd mаіn(String[] аrgs) { 
          A а = new A();  
          Single s = nеw Sіngle(); 
          Dоublе d = new Dоuble(); 
          } 
          }  
  class A{  

  } сlass Sіnglе ехtends A{  

  } сlass Double еxtеnds Sіngle{ 

  }
```

Maybe its too dumb, but can you help me to encode this to ASCII. Is it possible?

Comment: You wouldn't be trying to circumvent the terms and conditions of the site you're using, would you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's quite the string you have there.

I plugged what you've shown above - what's rendered as `'public'` - into a [Unicode "decoding" tool](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder). It just happened to be the first I ran across. That's not eight characters, it's 26:

```
U+0027 APOSTROPHE character (')
U+0026 AMPERSAND character (&)
U+0023 NUMBER SIGN character (#)
U+0031 DIGIT ONE character (1)
U+0030 DIGIT ZERO character (0)
U+0038 DIGIT EIGHT character (8)
U+0038 DIGIT EIGHT character (8)
U+003B SEMICOLON character (;)
U+0075 LATIN SMALL LETTER U character
U+0062 LATIN SMALL LETTER B character
U+006C LATIN SMALL LETTER L character
U+0026 AMPERSAND character (&)
U+0023 NUMBER SIGN character (#)
U+0031 DIGIT ONE character (1)
U+0031 DIGIT ONE character (1)
U+0031 DIGIT ONE character (1)
U+0030 DIGIT ZERO character (0)
U+003B SEMICOLON character (;)
U+0026 AMPERSAND character (&)
U+0023 NUMBER SIGN character (#)
U+0031 DIGIT ONE character (1)
U+0030 DIGIT ZERO character (0)
U+0038 DIGIT EIGHT character (8)
U+0039 DIGIT NINE character (9)
U+003B SEMICOLON character (;)
U+0027 APOSTROPHE character (')
```

...which resolves to `'&#1088;ubl&#1110;&#1089;'`. Those are HTML character entities in there:

> '
>   Cyrillic small letter er (p)
>   u
>   b
>   l
>   Cyrillic Byelorussian-Ukrainian i
>   Cyrillic small letter es (c)
>   '

...which, when rendered by a browser, resolves to (you guessed it): `'public'`. Browsers have no problem decoding HTML character entities, but IDEs do.

The site is trying to make it difficult to copy and paste code. Not foolproof, but maybe enough so that you won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I copied the text from your question into a text editor, then did an octal dump of the resulting file:

```
0000000    c   l   ?   ?   s   s  sp   G   ?   ?  sp   {  sp  sp  nl  sp
             6c63    b0d0    7373    4720    bed0    7b20    2020    200a
0000020   sp   ?  80   u   b   l   ?  96   ?  81  sp   s   t   a   t   ?
             d120    7580    6c62    96d1    81d1    7320    6174    d174
0000040   96   ?  81  sp   v   ?   ?   ?  96   d  sp   m   ?   ?   ?  96
             d196    2081    d076    d1be    6496    6d20    b0d0    96d1
0000060    n   (   S   t   r   i   n   g   [   ]  sp   ?   ?   r   g   s
             286e    7453    6972    676e    5d5b    d020    72b0    7367
0000100    )  sp   {  sp  nl  sp  sp  sp  sp   A  sp   ?   ?  sp   =  sp
             2029    207b    200a    2020    4120    d020    20b0    203d
0000120    n   e   w  sp   A   (   )   ;  sp  sp  nl  sp  sp  sp  sp   S
             656e    2077    2841    3b29    2020    200a    2020    5320
0000140    i   n   g   l   e  sp   s  sp   =  sp   n   ?   ?   w  sp   S
             6e69    6c67    2065    2073    203d    d06e    77b5    5320
0000160    ?  96   n   g   l   e   (   )   ;  sp  nl  sp  sp  sp  sp   D
             96d1    676e    656c    2928    203b    200a    2020    4420
0000200    ?   ?   u   b   l   ?   ?  sp   d  sp   =  sp   n   e   w  sp
             bed0    6275    d06c    20b5    2064    203d    656e    2077
0000220    D   ?   ?   u   b   l   e   (   )   ;  sp  nl  sp  sp   }  sp
             d044    75be    6c62    2865    3b29    0a20    2020    207d
0000240   nl   }  sp  sp  nl   c   l   a   s   s  sp   A   {  sp  sp  nl
             7d0a    2020    630a    616c    7373    4120    207b    0a20
0000260    }  nl   ?  81   l   a   s   s  sp   S   ?  96   n   g   l   ?
             0a7d    81d1    616c    7373    5320    96d1    676e    d06c
0000300    ?  sp   ?   ?   ?  85   t   e   n   d   s  sp   A   {  sp  sp
             20b5    b5d0    85d1    6574    646e    2073    7b41    2020
0000320   nl   }  nl   ?  81   l   a   s   s  sp   D   o   u   b   l   e
             7d0a    d10a    6c81    7361    2073    6f44    6275    656c
0000340   sp   ?   ?   x   t   ?   ?   n   d   s  sp   S   ?  96   n   g
             d020    78b5    d074    6eb5    7364    5320    96d1    676e
0000360    l   e   {  sp  nl   }  nl                                    
             656c    207b    7d0a    000a
```

As you can see, there are some "unknown" characters here - they are UTF-16 characters that happen to show up as the regular ascii, but they are in fact not from the standard `32 - 127` character set. This is probably a plot to prevent copying like you are doing.

I'm going to write a little translation utility… be right back. It looks like the character set is

```
D0B0 - a
D0BE - o
```

etc.